# Django-CMS AppHooks with conflicting urls?

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to use django-cms app hooks in a different way. I have only an app, with different website pages. For each page, i created an AppHook, since i want to have control of all of them with the cms.

To do that, inside the app, i did a package, with urls.py file for each of the page, example:

```
/urls
   /home_urls.py
   /portfolio_urls.py
   /contacts_urls.py
```

Here are the definition of some app hooks:

```
class WebsiteHome(CMSApp):
    name = _("cms-home")
    urls = ["website.urls.home_urls"]

apphook_pool.register(WebsiteHome)


class WebsiteServices(CMSApp):
    name = _("cms-services")
    urls = ["website.urls.services_urls"]

apphook_pool.register(WebsiteServices)
```

Anyway, the problem is: i don't have any control on the regular expressions. Each one, is entering on the first regular expression that it founds, in this case, the urlpattern in the

> website.urls.home_urls

Despite, having different apphHooks.

Example:

if i write a slug contacts (that has an apphook to WebsiteContacts), it still goes to the home_urls.py file, associated with the WebsiteHome (app hook).

Did anyone had a similiar problem?

---

Basically, what I'm trying to say is that it's something wrong with the regular expression. I can't make:

```
url(r'^$', [...]),
```

only:

```
url(r'^', [...]),
```

If I put the '$', it doesn't enter on any regex. If I take it, it enters always on the

> website.urls.home_urls.py

Despite the slugs having different Apphooks, associated with different urls.py files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `r'^/$'`?  I'm using `r'^/?$'` in some app-hook urls, but I wonder if `r'^$'` is failing for you because of a '/'?

Answer (score 0):

As you've defined each of those URL files as individual app hooks in CMS then they'll each get attached to a certain page in the CMS e.g.

```
www.mysite.com/home
www.mysite.com/contacts
www.mysite.com/services
etc
```

Because those URL files are attached to pages this should prevent conflict between `urlpatterns`. For example, I've got an URLs file attached to a CMS app called News which looks like this;

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news_detail'),
    url(r'^$', NewsListView.as_view(), name='news_list'),
)
```

Which is attached to a page at `mysite.com/news` so if I go to `mysite.com/news/myslug` I hit that `NewsDetailView` and if I go to `mysite.com/news` I hit `NewListView`.

Using this example, if you had a slug for a contact you'd go to `mysite.com/contacts/contact-slug` to hit that `NewsDetailView`.

And just a sidenote on the urlpatterns in case you're not aware, the `^` in the regex signifies the start of a pattern to match, and the `$` signifies the end. [URL dispatcher docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/)